# Trying to plot animation in Python using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot

Good morning all,

I have been working on a small personal project, but am now stuck in the final plotting phase.
So far, I have created a 4 dimensional array called "colored_map":

- dimension 1: frame number (0-499) which I'm trying to iterate over
- dimension 2 and 3: x and y positions
- dimension 4: RGB values of each element

In short, I am trying to plot each frame by iterating over the first dimension of the array, and clear the plot after each iteration so the output looks like a "video".
I have tried the following piece of code, but it does not replace/ overwrite the previous fig:

```
for j in range(0,500):
    img = colored_map[j]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
    #ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    #ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.pause(1)
```

I also tried the below piece of code which I found somewhere else, but it only creates the first frame:

```
#Setting up the figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_axis_off()
im = ax.imshow(colored_map[0])

#Animate function to iterate over successive frames
def animate(i):
    im.set_data(colored_map[i])
    return im

#Calling the animator to put the different frames together
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=500, interval=20)

plt.show()
```

You can create the colored_map array using the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, colors

density = 0.8
prob = 0.9
#You could reduce n_iterations (= 1st dim) and forest_size (2nd and 3rd dim) to create an smaller array
n_iterations = 200
forest_size = [101,101]
black = [0,0,0]
green = [0,153,0]
orange = [255,128,0]

states = np.zeros((n_iterations,forest_size[0],forest_size[1]))
states[0] = np.random.choice([0,1],forest_size,p=[1-density, density])
states[0,np.random.randint(1,forest_size[0]-2),np.random.randint(1,forest_size[1]-2)] = 2

for i in range(1,n_iterations):
    states[i]=states[i-1].copy()
    for x in range(1, forest_size[0]-1):
        for y in range(1, forest_size[1]-1):
            if states[i-1,x,y]==2:
                states[i,x,y]=0
                    states[i,x+1,y]= np.random.choice([1,2],1,p=[1-prob,prob])[0]
                if states[i-1,x-1,y]==1:
                    states[i,x-1,y]= np.random.choice([1,2],1,p=[1-prob,prob])[0]
                if states[i-1,x,y+1]==1:
                    states[i,x,y+1]= np.random.choice([1,2],1,p=[1-prob,prob])[0]
                if states[i-1,x,y-1]==1:
                    states[i,x,y-1]= np.random.choice([1,2],1,p=[1-prob,prob])[0]

colored_map = np.zeros((n_iterations,forest_size[0],forest_size[1],3),dtype=np.uint8) 

for i in range(0,colored_map.shape[0]):
    for x in range(0,colored_map.shape[1]):
        for y in range(0,colored_map.shape[2]):       
            cur_value = states[i,x,y].copy()
            if cur_value == 0:
                colored_map[i,x,y] = black
            if cur_value == 1:
                colored_map[i,x,y] = green
            if cur_value == 2:
                colored_map[i,x,y] = orange
```

Can someone please help me by pointing out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Your second code (with `FuncAnimation`) works perfectly fine with random data. If it does not work for you, then you need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including a toy dataset

Comment: @DizietAsahi does it animate the different frames? The only thing I see when I use that block of code (in Jupyter Notebook) is the first frame. I'm trying to create a verifiable example, but it's hard to make it fit 500 characters...

Comment: @DizietAsahi I added the block of code that creates the "colored_map" array. Hope this helps.

Comment: Works fine for me. code: https://pastebin.com/v1gCynaa result: https://imgur.com/a/3KBmhYy